# Upgrading Python3 Without Breaking Access to lib Folder

Tags: upgrade, libraries, python3

Upgrading Python3 package is always a big pain for me. Every time I upgrade from one version, e.g. 3.7.0, to another, e.g. 3.7.1, my python script loses access to my `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` folder. I have to revert back to the previous version, i.e. 3.7.0, to allow my script have access to this folder again.

My question is simple. How to upgrade Python3 while maintaining access to the above lib folder. Should I create a `/usr/local/lib/python3.7.1/` folder? I doubt since we are still under the numbering `3.7` for Python.

There has to be a mean to upgrade Python subversions without breaking access to the lib.

Here's the kind of error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./script.py", line 20, in <module>
import urllib3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'
```

But I have `urllib3` in `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` So why reverting back to previous 3.7.0 would reenable lib access?

Comment: You probably will enjoy virtualenv. https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: What OS are you on, what is the upgrade command you are using, what is the exec command (`python script.py` or `./script.py` with a shebang etc)?

Comment: OS X 10.11.6 – `brew upgrade python3` – Script comes from [here](https://www.prxbx.com/forums/showthread.php?tid=2191&pid=19385#pid19385) (ProxHTTPSProxyMII for HTTPS filtering) – Command: `./ProxHTTPSProxy.py`

Comment: I followed the above *virtualenvs* guide and can even run the Python script as follows: `pipenv run python ./ProxHTTPSProxy.py` Unfortunately, when I upgrade Python from `3.7.0` to `3.7.1` I've got plenty of error messages that relate to `pipenv` and my script no longer runs. Why is it so difficult to upgrade Python without breaking everything? I'm exhausted by so much complications and hours of staring at my screen in an attempt to solve this and for doing a simple thing as upgrading Pyhon itself!